# How to hide certain columns when another cell shows a specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-365

This is what I want to happen:

If Cell F6 is blank does nothing.
If Cell F6 the Cell has specific text saying 'A' only then I want full columns N, O, Q, T and U to be hidden, the whole columns hidden.
If Cell F6 the Cell has specific text saying 'B' only then I want full columns L, M, P, R and S to be hidden, the whole columns hidden but not other columns hidden so the above for cell saying 'A' would re-appear if 'B' was typed in.
Then if Cell B7 has no blanks (any date or text has been typed in) I want all columns to be unhidden again.

I want this in real time too so not having to 'run' macro but as soon as typed either A or B into Cell F6 and press tab or enter then the columns hide.

This is what I have tried and got the least errors:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Range("F6").Value = "A" Then
    Columns("N:N, O:O, Q:Q, T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Else
    Columns("N:N, O:O, Q:Q, T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  If Range("F6").Value = "B" Then
    Columns("L:L, M:M, P:P, R:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Else
    Columns("L:L, M:M, P:P, R:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  If Range("B7").Value = "A" Then
    Columns("L:L, M:M, N:N, O:O P:P, Q:Q, R:R, T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  End If
End Sub
```

The error I get:

> Block if without end if

I've edited to the following:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Range("F6").Value = "A" Then
    Columns("N:N, O:O, Q:Q, T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End If
  If Range("F6").Value = "B" Then
    Columns("L:L, M:M, P:P, R:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End If
  If Range("B7").Value = "A" Then
    Columns("L:L, M:M, N:N, O:O P:P, Q:Q, R:R, T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  End If
End Sub
```

But now I get error

> Type mismatch

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser, please note that this is not a free code writing service. You have already broken down the task into individual steps. A search for each one should provide solutions, it is then a question of putting it all together. Once you've started, post your code here or on https://stackoverflow.com if you hit a problem and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: you need an `end if` after every `if` clause, In your case you are missing two of them.

Comment: There is an implied "similar" for these; `if` <-versus-> `(` and `endif` <-versus-> `)` - i.e. if you have one of them, then there has to be a matching one of the other; and "nesting" matters. the `if` / `endif` pair "alone" is ok, i.e. the `else` is optional.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: My latest try unfortunately didn't work

Comment: I don't think the `Columns()` command can take a noncontiguous range, or doesn't understand your range. One solution is to have 4 `Columns()` command, one for each column you are hiding. Do this for the other `Columns()` command. I think that solves your question, now on to the next one...